# Recalculating Road Segment Parity based off two other Fields within ArcMap

Tags: python, arcmap

I am working within ArcMap and attempting to use Python to automate the process of creating a Parity field which will be drawing its attributes from the values of two other fields From_L and To_L. Both of these fields will have a combination of  EE / OO / EO /OE. I thought I'd be able to create a simple if / elif statement to populate the field, but when it runs though nothing happens..

```
def ReCalc(PARITY_L):
    if From_L == "E" and To_L == "E":             
        return "E"
    elif From_L == "O" & To_L == "O":
        return "O"
    elif From_L != To_L:
        return "M"
```

I am sure this is quite a simple fix, but I have probably spend too long looking at it and am now blind to the statement..

Any help or directions would be appreciated.

Comment: Careful of the devious ampersand operator.

Comment: Sorry, let me elaborate a bit. There's a bitwise AND operator (`&`) in your function that is surely unintended: replace it with `and` and see if there's some improvement.

Comment: Ah, I didn't mean for that to be in there. Actually I was able to fix my problem! My original equation was correct, but the fact that I was not calling both the "From_L" and the "To_L" fields in the definition was causing issues.